# How to correct "The condition parameter accepts a 'bool' argument"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
left = input(6, title="Left", group="Support and Resistance")
right = input(8, title="Right", group="Support and Resistance")

hih = ta.pivothigh(high, left, right)
lol = ta.pivotlow(low, left, right)

top = ta.valuewhen(hih, high[right], 0)
bot = ta.valuewhen(lol, low[right], 0)
```

In PineScript version 5 it says error:

> The `condition` parameter of the `ta.valuewhen` function accepts a 'bool' argument. To avoid potential unexpected results, pass a 'bool' value or expression to this parameter.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error, it is a warning.

You can cast the output of `pivothigh()` and `pivotlow()` functions to `bool` if you want to eliminate that warning. In your use case, it won't make any difference.

```
hih = bool(ta.pivothigh(high, left, right))
lol = bool(ta.pivotlow(low, left, right))
```